# About period of elliptic points

Tags: modular-forms

I'm reading about modular forms and I've seen some results which only make use of elliptic points of period 2 and 3 (and cusps). I would like to know if it's possible to find elliptic points of period different from 2 and 3? Maybe it's a silly question, but in my book I haven't seen elliptic points having period say 4, 5, etc. Is this related to the fact that $X(1)$ has only two elliptic points $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})i$ and $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})\mu_{3}$ of periods 2 and 3, respectively?

Comment: Possible orders are 2, 3, 4, or 6.

Comment: Why this happens? I'm confused because in page 67 of Diamond and Shurman's modular forms book it says that the periods lie in $\{1,2,3\}$ (the book is A First Course in Modular Forms).

Comment: The problem of torsion subgroups was definitely closed by Mazur: each group of torsion of an elliptic curve is isomorphe to one of the 15 following groups $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ where $1\le n\le10$ or $n=12$; $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2$ where $1\le n\le 4$. Besides each of this 15 cases occurs infinitely many times.

Comment: I don't see how the torsion subgroup of an elliptic curve is related to the elliptic points of a general modular curve $X(N)$. Could you explain me about it? (Maybe you mean some version of modularity theorem or something like this?)

Comment: Piquito's comment refers to a true theorem (although in somewhat garbled form), but one which has nothing to do with the question: the torsion subgroups of modular elliptic curves have nothing to do with the stabilisers of points in the upper half-plane.

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is a finite-index subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathbf{Z})$, and $z$ is  a point in the upper half-plane, then the $\Gamma$-stabiliser of $z$ is a subgroup of the $PSL_2(\mathbf{Z})$-stabiliser, and that has order 1, 2 or 3 by a theorem you evidently already know. So the $\Gamma$-stabiliser must also have order 1, 2, or 3. (If you work with subgroups of $SL_2$ rather than $PSL_2$, and your group contains $-1$, then the possibilities are now $2, 4, 6$ rather than $1,2,3$.)

Comment: I think that page 55 in the book you mention (Diamond and Shurman) answers your question.